# git remote different remotes for fetch and push

Tags: git

when I do `git remote -v` I get

```
origin  git@xxx.yyy.cc:name fetch)
origin  git@xxx.yyy.cc:name (push)
```

Why there are two separate entries for `fetch` and `push` remotes? What would be the case where someone would want a different remotes for these two actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this helpful blog](http://sleepycoders.blogspot.sg/2012/05/different-git-push-pullfetch-urls.html) discusses, one case where you would want separate remotes for fetching and pushing is if you forked someone else's repository.  In this case, you would want to pull from the main repository and then push to yours.